# BTreeSet.range alternative

Tags: rust

I have a `BTreeSet` and need the largest element less than a given element.  It looks like I'd use something like:

```
let set: BTreeSet<T> = ...;
let e: T = ...;
let result = e.range(Bound::Unbounded, Bound::Excluded(e)).last();
```

but `BTreeSet::range` is unstable.  How else can I do this?  I know I could use `set.iter().rposition(|e2| e2 < e)` (or something like that), but I'd like logarithmic time, not linear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way, *yet*. There is [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1195) out to add these method to `BTreeMap`, and then to `BTreeSet`.